# Removing duplicates on mysql table [the table is > 2Gb]

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

**Problem** - we have many duplicate rows in our tables which makes the calculations non-accurate

**The solution** I tried - I wrote a delete inner join query that shall delete the duplicates (based on my research this is the fastest method), tested it on staging and it worked, run on the production hoping it will last max 1-2 days,

Here is the query I was using:

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1
    INNER JOIN
table t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id 
AND t1.col1 = t2.col1
AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
AND t1.col3 = t2.col3
AND t1.col4 = t2.col4
```

**Problems with the solution** -

I expected the query to be run some hours or 2-3 days but when I tried this solution of the entire table it took 4 days and it was still on and I had to kill the process.

the query has been running for 4 days and it is still on, I tried on a smaller table which was a segment of my original table and again it took hours and hours. I cannot afford to have a query run on my table for weeks as I am doing lots of calculation on this table and I don't want my table to get locked.

Comment: DO you have index on those columns? If don't try adding compound index then try it.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a large number of rows from a table is very expensive.   I would recommend creating a new table with the rows you want and then (maybe) repopulating the original table.

You can start with:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_t AS
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM t t1
    WHERE t1.id = (SELECT MIN(t2.id)
                   FROM t t2
                   WHERE t2.col1 = t2.col1 AND
                         t2.col2 = t2.col2 AND
                         t2.col3 = t2.col3 AND
                         t2.col4 = t2.col4
                  );
```

For this to work in a reasonable amount of time, you need an index on `t(col1, col2, col3, col4)`!  The index is quite important (and might take some time to build).

Then, you can decide if you want to repopulate your original table.  If you have validated that the above is correct, you can do:

```
truncate table t;

insert into t
    select * from temp_t;
```

Of course, you should backup your table/database before doing something like this.

Comment: i created another table as well but did not try the indexes. I will put index and will give this a try, thanks a lot.